# Hiding component with *ngIf sometimes leaves weird padding

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to hide my header in some components based on my route. My code is rather simple I just subscribe to the route and check if it matches my route with a regex:

```
this._router.events.pipe(
  filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
).subscribe(
  x =>  {
  const regex = /\/courses\/(.\/*)/g;
  const match = regex.test(x['url']);
  this.showHeader = !match;
});
```

And in my template I render my header accordingly:

```
<app-layout-header *ngIf="showHeader"></app-layout-header>
```

Now that works as intended most of the time but sometimes my browser doesn't render my template correctly and instead leaves a mysterious padding to the body:

[image: padding issue]

I've tried setting padding: 0 on my body but changes nothing. An alternative "hack" could be to set a negative margin on my content in the specific components, but that would require me to play with z-indexes as well which makes for a pretty ugly solution.

Why is my page not being rendered correctly?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your main script and then while at that breakpoint put a breakpoint on the body element so you can see what code is making the change?

Comment: Do you mean setting a breakpoint on the body html element? I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: In case you run into something like this again check out https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom .  DOM change breakpoints are useful if you are trying to figure out how some attribute got set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten I was adding padding to the body on a scroll event in typescript in one of my other components. So when redirected from that page it would leave the white space. I fixed it by resetting the body padding to 0 in ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please wrap the the below section code inside setTimeout()

```
const regex = /\/courses\/(.\/*)/g;
const match = regex.test(x['url']);
this.showHeader = !match;
```

Comment: i wrapped it in a timeout with 0 - no difference :(

Comment: In body tag, where padding-top is getting set. can you share that code?

Comment: figured out why it rendered the odd space .. thanks for your effort